# Error parsing data : JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, php, android, json

I am making a register form. I have two classes: `ClientServer.java` and `JSONParser.java`

**ClientServer.java:**

```
package com.example.mapsdemo;        
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;      
    import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;



    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;

    public class Clientserver extends Activity {            
        EditText username,email,password;
        Button signup,intent;
        String mpostusername,mpostpassword,mpostemail;

           private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
         JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_clientserver);        

            username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);

            email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);

            password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

            signup  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.signup);

            intent = (Button)findViewById(R.id.go);

                    //Setup the Button's OnClickListener
                    signup.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            //Get the data
                             new CreateNewAccount().execute();

                                Log.d("my", "in onclick...create new account executed");
                }
            });

                    intent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Intent i = new Intent(Clientserver.this,MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                    });
        }

        class CreateNewAccount extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

            /**
             * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
             * */

            /**
             * Creating product
             * */
            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

                Log.d("my", "in doInBackground()");     

                mpostusername = username.getText().toString();
                 mpostemail = email.getText().toString();
                 mpostpassword = password.getText().toString();


                    Log.d("my", "getting inputs is executed");
                 List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",mpostusername));
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",mpostemail));
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",mpostpassword));
                    Log.d("my", "parameter adding executed");

                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest("http://<ip_address>/android_connect/register.php","POST", params);        

                if(json!=null){
                      // do something                    
                Log.d("my", "http request made successfully");

                try {
                    int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);         
                    Log.d("my", "JSON tag_success is working");                         
                    if (success == 1) {                         
                        Log.d("my", "in success=1"); 
                        // successfully created product
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);

                        // closing this screen
                        finish();
                    } else {                            
                        Log.d("my", "In else");                          
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

**JSONParser.java**:

```
package com.example.mapsdemo;    
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;     
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.util.Log;     
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";     
    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {     
        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method.equals("POST")){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient                    
                Log.d("my", "method equals POST is working");
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                Log.d("my", "HTTp client is working");
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                Log.d("my", "HTTp post is working");                    
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));                    
                Log.d("my", "url encoded");     
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);                    
                Log.d("my", "HTTp response is working");
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();                    
                Log.d("my", "HTTp entity is working");                  
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
                Log.d("my", "getcontent is working");     
            }else if(method.equals("GET")){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);     
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;     
    }
}
```

**db_connect.php**

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect('http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/phpmyadmin', 'xxxx', 'xxxxx');
if (!$connection){
    die("Database Connection Failed" . mysql_error());
}
$select_db = mysql_select_db('accountsb');
if (!$select_db){
    die("Database Selection Failed" . mysql_error());
}
```

**register.php**

```
<?php
    require('db_connect.php');    
   $response = array();            
   $username= $_POST['username'];       
   $email = $_POST['email'];            
   $password = $_POST['password'];              

        $query = "INSERT INTO `account` (username,email,password) VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$password')";
        $result = mysql_query($query); 
        if($result){
  $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "account successfully created.";     
        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);                
        }
        else
        {
             $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
         }
    ?>
```

**ERROR:**

0-06 12:16:45.340: E/JSON Parser(8630): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value

Here is my logcat filtered **log**:

```
10-06 12:31:09.800: D/my(11813): in onclick...create new account executed
10-06 12:31:09.800: D/my(11813): in doInBackground()
10-06 12:31:09.800: D/my(11813): getting inputs is executed
10-06 12:31:09.800: D/my(11813): parameter adding executed
10-06 12:31:09.800: D/my(11813): method equals POST is working
10-06 12:31:09.800: D/my(11813): HTTp client is working
10-06 12:31:09.800: D/my(11813): HTTp post is working
10-06 12:31:09.800: D/my(11813): url encoded
10-06 12:31:12.090: D/my(11813): HTTp response is working
10-06 12:31:12.090: D/my(11813): HTTp entity is working
10-06 12:31:12.090: D/my(11813): getcontent is working
```

**NOTE:** 
1. I have seen many similar questions on SO and tried many solutions, but It didn't work after trying about 2 hours So, plz don't mark as dulicate.plz help.

2. My php code suffers from SQL injection, I know. But, it is for just practising and I will edit them with mysqli and PDO in future.

Comment: Post Your `JSON` response

Comment: @ṁᾶƔƏňツ ok i'm editing

Comment: @ṁᾶƔƏňツ i have edited.

Comment: I think you are not getting json response instead getting some html tags. Check whether you getting correct response from your server and post that `JSON` response.

Comment: The point is that your code might be perfectly all right, as far as we can tell. The server isn't returning JSON. That might be a server problem, or you might be hitting the wrong URL, but we can't tell from here.

Comment: @SathishKumar how to find jason response from server?

Comment: @chiastic-security i am putting urls as weel...wait..editing

Comment: Debug and check this line `HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);`

Comment: 1) Send the request from a web browser and look at the response using the browsers "developer" interface.  2) Use a packet sniffer.  3) Change your app to print the content instead of parsing it.

Comment: `http://<ip_address>/android_connect/register.php?username=&email=&password=`, add required credentials in URL, and load it in browser, you will get response.

Comment: @chiastic-security I have put the url now...can you help me?

Comment: sorry i too don't aware on PHP

Answer (score 0):

Try to place isset in your PHP to make sure they get all the values (works like required field) Also I think the problem is in your querying

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO accounts(email, password, username) 
    values ('$email','$password','$username')");
```

Try this. Also if your URL seems to be the problem in command prompt use ipconfig and get the top most ipv4 address and make that as your port.

Answer (score 0):

//Json Handler

public class ServiceHandler {

```
static String response = null;
public final static int GET = 1;
public final static int POST = 2;

public ServiceHandler() {

}

/**
 * Making service call
 * @url - url to make request
 * @method - http request method
 * */
public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method) {
    return this.makeServiceCall(url, method, null);
}

/**
 * Making service call
 * @url - url to make request
 * @method - http request method
 * @params - http request params
 * */
public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {
    try {
        // http client
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

        // Checking http request method type
        if (method == POST) {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            // adding post params
            if (params != null) {
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            }

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        } else if (method == GET) {
            // appending params to url
            if (params != null) {
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils
                        .format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
            }
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        }
        System.out.println("Status in url =====" + httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;

}
```

}