# Warnings: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known

Tags: java, php, android, json, wamp

I have asked this question about 2 hours ago : [Error parsing data : JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26211420/error-parsing-data-jsonexception-value-br-of-type-java-lang-string-cannot-be)  ,

After trying some solutions, i found that the error is in php files.

the problem is that i am not so good at PHP...Can anyone help me.

**Essentials from previous question:**

I am making a register form. I have two classes: `ClientServer.java` and `JSONParser.java`

**ClientServer.java:**

```
package com.example.mapsdemo;        
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;      
    import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;



    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;

    public class Clientserver extends Activity {            
        EditText username,email,password;
        Button signup,intent;
        String mpostusername,mpostpassword,mpostemail;

           private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
         JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_clientserver);        

            username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);

            email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);

            password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

            signup  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.signup);

            intent = (Button)findViewById(R.id.go);

                    //Setup the Button's OnClickListener
                    signup.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            //Get the data
                             new CreateNewAccount().execute();

                                Log.d("my", "in onclick...create new account executed");
                }
            });

                    intent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Intent i = new Intent(Clientserver.this,MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                    });
        }

        class CreateNewAccount extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

            /**
             * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
             * */

            /**
             * Creating product
             * */
            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

                Log.d("my", "in doInBackground()");     

                mpostusername = username.getText().toString();
                 mpostemail = email.getText().toString();
                 mpostpassword = password.getText().toString();


                    Log.d("my", "getting inputs is executed");
                 List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",mpostusername));
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",mpostemail));
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",mpostpassword));
                    Log.d("my", "parameter adding executed");

                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest("http://<ip_address>/android_connect/register.php","POST", params);        

                if(json!=null){
                      // do something                    
                Log.d("my", "http request made successfully");

                try {
                    int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);         
                    Log.d("my", "JSON tag_success is working");                         
                    if (success == 1) {                         
                        Log.d("my", "in success=1"); 
                        // successfully created product
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);

                        // closing this screen
                        finish();
                    } else {                            
                        Log.d("my", "In else");                          
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

**JSONParser.java**:

```
package com.example.mapsdemo;    
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;     
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.util.Log;     
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";     
    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {     
        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method.equals("POST")){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient                    
                Log.d("my", "method equals POST is working");
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                Log.d("my", "HTTp client is working");
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                Log.d("my", "HTTp post is working");                    
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));                    
                Log.d("my", "url encoded");     
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);                    
                Log.d("my", "HTTp response is working");
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();                    
                Log.d("my", "HTTp entity is working");                  
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
                Log.d("my", "getcontent is working");     
            }else if(method.equals("GET")){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);     
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;     
    }
}
```

**db_connect.php**

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect('http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/phpmyadmin', 'xxxx', 'xxxxx');
if (!$connection){
    die("Database Connection Failed" . mysql_error());
}
$select_db = mysql_select_db('accountsb');
if (!$select_db){
    die("Database Selection Failed" . mysql_error());
}
```

**register.php**

```
<?php
    require('db_connect.php');    
   $response = array();            
   $username= $_POST['username'];       
   $email = $_POST['email'];            
   $password = $_POST['password'];              

        $query = "INSERT INTO `account` (username,email,password) VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$password')";
        $result = mysql_query($query); 
        if($result){
  $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "account successfully created.";     
        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);                
        }
        else
        {
             $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
         }
    ?>
```

**ERROR:**

```
0-06 12:16:45.340: E/JSON Parser(8630): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Here is my logcat filtered **log**:

```
10-06 12:31:09.800: D/my(11813): in onclick...create new account executed
10-06 12:31:09.800: D/my(11813): in doInBackground()
10-06 12:31:09.800: D/my(11813): getting inputs is executed
10-06 12:31:09.800: D/my(11813): parameter adding executed
10-06 12:31:09.800: D/my(11813): method equals POST is working
10-06 12:31:09.800: D/my(11813): HTTp client is working
10-06 12:31:09.800: D/my(11813): HTTp post is working
10-06 12:31:09.800: D/my(11813): url encoded
10-06 12:31:12.090: D/my(11813): HTTp response is working
10-06 12:31:12.090: D/my(11813): HTTp entity is working
10-06 12:31:12.090: D/my(11813): getcontent is working
```

**NOTE:** 
1. I have seen many similar questions on SO and tried many solutions, but It didn't work after trying about 2 hours So, plz don't mark as dulicate.plz help.

2. My php code suffers from SQL injection, I know. But, it is for just practising and I will edit them with mysqli and PDO in future.

**UPDATE:**
Error is in my php files....when i try to open `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/android_connect/register.php`.

it shows following warnings:

[image]

There are 3 erros in which 2 are warning:

```
mysql_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\wamp\www\android_connect\db_connect.php on line 2
```

and

```
mysql_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\wamp\www\android_connect\db_connect.php on line 2
```

Comment: Not sure if this will help but add the `Accept` request property to your header and set it to `application/json`

Comment: how to add...i don't know php well

Comment: You don't add a request property to your php. It's a "request" property. What is making your request? Android. So add it to your android code.

Comment: @PedroOliveira can you explain in answer? i'll highly appreciate.

Comment: On your `mysql_connect` change your **address** to `xxx.xxx.xxx.xx` only. Remove the rest.

Comment: @PedroOliveira thanks  it worked, but now showing a different error: database selection failed.

Comment: Now you have to select your database. Use `mysql_select_db('accountsb', $connection);`.Remember to pass the connection as 2º parameter. Good luck

Comment: @PedroOliveira thank you very much....You are such a big help...One suggestion: can you write a small answer?...so that all visitors can also get benefit..i'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So has requested by the OP:

The problem was that you were trying to connect to a host that was incorrectly typed. You need to connect only using the IP:PORT of the host.

Also you need to pass the connection as 2º parameter of the `mysql_select_db` function.

For more syntax refer to: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Have a great day.